# What is the difference between Pages and Shared and can we use different folders?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am browsing and still learning about Blazor, but one thing I am unable to understand - why are there prepared folders for "Pages" and "Shared", and what's the difference between the two?

- What is the difference between Pages and Shared?
- Where do we stored our custom controls?

[image: solution explorer view]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "custom controls"? Do you mean C# methods?

Answer (score 7):

Pages and components are essentially the same thing, except a page has one or more `@page` directives identifying which URL can be used to render them.

A `@page` directive will be turned into a `[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RouteAttribute("/XXX")]` attribute on the component class that is generated from your razor file.

Blazor will reflect over your whole assembly for types that are decorated with `[RouteAttribute]`. This means pages can be wherever you want them to be.

The same is true for Components. The reason are able to put them in the `Shared` folder by default is because `/_Imports.razor` has a `@using YouAppName.Shared` in it. If you want to put your components in other namespaces you can either

1. Add the namespace to the _Imports.razor file
2. Add a `@using WhateverNamespace` to the top of your consuming page/component.
3. Include the namespace in the markup `<WhateverNamespace.SomeComponent/>`

https://blazor-university.com/routing/defining-routes/